# Menu: What kind is this?

Tags: javascript, browser, menu

I dont know what it is called but you can see on this page http://carleypelletier.deviantart.com/gallery/#_browse if you click on a category you'll get a list and if there is a subcategory there will be a > at the end. When clicking this the menu text moves left off the menu and the new categories are in. How do i do this type of menu? i'm open to any libs. It would be nice if i can fill it using json or a config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Chinese menu](http://www.sothink.com/page/drop-down-menu/jquery-dropdown-menu.html) of jQuery drop downs, you are looking for a "drill down style of menu, on the menu you will see a "jQuery iPod-style Drilldown Menu" which is pretty close to what you want, they just used multiple ones.

A working example of one is [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/)